# Bindind resources control with content control WPF

Tags: wpf

I've just started learning WPF. However, now I'm having issues with my UI (which remains empty). This is the code I'm using; What I'm trying to do is to display the properties of the `River` in the UI.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:River x:Key="theRiver" Name="Colorado River" MilesLong="1450" />
    <StackPanel x:Key="stackey" DataContext="theRiver">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="key" DataType="{x:Type local:River}" >
                <Border x:Name="bdr" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="12" Padding="2">
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txt" FontFamily="Bookman old style">
                            <Run Text="The"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Run Text="is"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MilesLong}" />
                            <Run Text="miles long." />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="bdr" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="CornerRadius" Value="40"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Background="Gold" DataContext="{StaticResource theRiver}>-->
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=stackey}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Background="Gold" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.

```
<StackPanel x:Key="stackey" DataContext="theRiver">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="key" DataType="{x:Type local:River}" >
```

Here you want to provide an unnamed DataTemplate for the type that will be loaded into the ContentControl. The StackPanel wrapper here is unnecessary, as is the x:Key on the DataTemplate.

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=stackey}"
```

This says that the source for the ContentControl's content is the StackPanel you declared in your resources, rather than an instance of River.

Corrected/working code looks like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:River x:Key="theRiver" Name="Colorado River" MilesLong="1450" />

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:River}">
        <Border x:Name="bdr"
                    BorderBrush="Blue"
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    CornerRadius="12"
                    Padding="2">
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txt" FontFamily="Bookman old style">
                        <Run Text="The" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Run Text="is" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MilesLong}" />
                        <Run Text="miles long." />
                    </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="bdr" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="CornerRadius" Value="40" />
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Background="Gold" DataContext="{StaticResource theRiver}>  -->
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="10"
                    Background="Gold"
                    Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource theRiver}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Good news! If you're happy with one of the provided answers, please upvote it to mark the question as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the DataTemplate in Windows.Resources like below (remove the Stackpanel):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="stackey" DataType="{x:Type local:River}" >
            <Border x:Name="bdr" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="12" Padding="2">
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" FontFamily="Bookman old style">
        <Run Text="The"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Run Text="is"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MilesLong}" />
        <Run Text="miles long." />
      </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="bdr" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="CornerRadius" Value="40"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and then bind your ContentControl like

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  DataContext="{StaticResource theRiver}" Content="{StaticResource theRiver}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource stackey}"   Margin="10" Background="Gold" />
```